# Is $\mathcal{V}\otimes\mathcal{W}$ defined as a double dual?

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

I've been working through Tensor Spaces and Exterior Algebra by Yokonuma, and he first defines the tensor product of two $k$-vector fields $\mathcal{V}$ and $\mathcal{W}$ as the unique (up to isomorphism) $k$-vector field $\mathcal{U}$ with bilinear mapping $\otimes:\mathcal{V}\times\mathcal{W}\rightarrow\mathcal{U}$ through which we can factor any other bilinear mapping from $\mathcal{V}\times\mathcal{W}$ into a $k$-vector field $\mathcal{U}'$.

He then goes on to offer the definitions (abbreviated for our purposes here) $$\mathcal{V}\otimes\mathcal{W}=\mathscr{L}(\mathcal{V}^*,\mathcal{W}^*;k),$$ together with the mappings $_v\otimes_w\in\mathcal{V}\otimes\mathcal{W}$ defined by $$_v\otimes_w=\langle\phi(v)\psi(w):\phi\in\mathcal{V}^*\wedge \psi\in\mathcal{W}^*\rangle$$ for all $v\in\mathcal{V}$ and $w\in\mathcal{W}$, grouped into the mapping $\otimes:\mathcal{V}\times\mathcal{W}\rightarrow\mathcal{V}\otimes\mathcal{W}$ defined by $$\otimes=\langle_v\otimes_w:(v,w)\in\mathcal{V}\times\mathcal{W}\rangle.$$ He then asserts that $(\mathcal{V}\otimes\mathcal{W},\otimes)$ is a canonical choice for the tensor product of $\mathcal{V}$ and $\mathcal{W}$, as all other choices would be isomorphic in all the important ways mentioned above.

It occurred to me that since $$\mathcal{V}^*=\mathscr{L}(\mathcal{V};k)$$ for any $k$-vector field $\mathcal{V}$, we have that $$\mathcal{V}\otimes\mathcal{W}=\mathscr{L}(\mathcal{V}^*,\mathcal{W}^*;k)=\mathscr{L}\big(\mathscr{L}(\mathcal{V};k),\mathscr{L}(\mathcal{W};k);k\big),$$ so it seems like we are actually defining $\mathcal{V}\otimes\mathcal{W}$ here as a kind of double dual for $\mathcal{V}$ and $\mathcal{W}$.  I was just wondering if this was a correct interpretation, and if so whether there is somewhere I might be able to read more about it -- (finite dimensional) vector spaces are canonically isomorphic to their double duals, but it seems like we are actually taking a double-dual as the definition of a tensor product here, which is of course a vector space. It seems to me like this kind of definition would naturally give rise to the unique factoring properties mentioned at the top in Yokonuma's first definition, but some more in-depth reading on the topic would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This double dualisation trick only works for finite-dimensional vector spaces.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown This sounds like something along the lines of what I'm looking for -- why would this interpretation fail for (for example) $\mathbb{C}^\omega$ or $\mathbb{C}^{\omega^+}$?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown It is my understanding that the dual of $\mathbb{C}^\omega$ would have a cardinality strictly larger than $|\mathbb{C}^\omega|=\mathfrak{c}$, but does this mean that the tensor product $\mathbb{C}^\omega\otimes\mathbb{C}^\omega$ is not still a double dual for $\mathbb{C}^\omega\times\mathbb{C}^\omega=\mathbb{C}^{2\omega}$ which satisfies $|\mathbb{C}^{2\omega}|<|\mathbb{C}^\omega\otimes\mathbb{C}^\omega|$? If we look at topological duals with bounded functionals does the interpretation still  hold, since the cardinality does often match up in that case?